# How does is.na(df) work if a dataframe is a list of lists?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame and I want to find out which values in it are NA. So I can do `is.na(df)`. This works great, but I don't understand why. I thought that a data.frame is a list of lists, so asking `is.na(df)` would tell me whether each of those lists are NA, which they're of course not (because they're lists). So I thought it would return a vector of `FALSE`, one for each column.

Instead it somehow does something else. How does this work?

Comment: have a look at `is.na.data.frame `, it passes the `is.na` function across the columns one ata time. So for example, if `x` is a column in a dataframe then see what happens with `x <- c(1:3, NA) ; is.na(x)`

Comment: Most data frames aren't lists of lists, but lists of vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the code and see what the `.data.frame`-method does:

```
> methods(is.na)
 [1] is.na,abIndex-method       is.na,denseMatrix-method   is.na,indMatrix-method    
 [4] is.na,nsparseMatrix-method is.na,nsparseVector-method is.na,sparseMatrix-method 
 [7] is.na,sparseVector-method  is.na.coxph.penalty*       is.na.data.frame          
[10] is.na.data.table*          is.na.numeric_version      is.na.POSIXlt             
[13] is.na.raster*              is.na.ratetable*           is.na.Surv                
[16] is.na.times*              
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
> is.na.data.frame
function (x) 
{
    y <- if (length(x)) {
        do.call("cbind", lapply(x, "is.na"))
    }
    else matrix(FALSE, length(row.names(x)), 0)
    if (.row_names_info(x) > 0L) 
        rownames(y) <- row.names(x)
    y
}
<bytecode: 0x7fc7187b5f48>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So in most instances. when there is anything in a dataframe, it's just first making a list of logical vectors with is.na and `cbind`-ing them (which returns a matrix object.)

```
do.call("cbind", lapply(x, "is.na"))
```